# Converting byte[] to pdf, rotating 180 degrees, back to byte[] and to response.outputstream

Tags: arrays, pdf, model-view-controller, rotation

I am trying to rotate a pdf document 180 degrees. Stored as a byte[] initially, it should be returned to the same, so that I can write it to the outputstream to our customers. This is my working code without rotation:

```
            if (pdfurl == null)
                return View(errorview);
            var response = Response;
            var getbyteresult = WebService.GetPDFAsByteArray(pdfurl);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(getbyteresult);
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
            "attachment;filename=label.pdf");
            response.Buffer = true;
            ms.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
            response.End();
            return View("~/Views/Order/pdf.cshtml");
```

I've tried several libraries (itext, freesharp, spire), none of correctly manipulates and outputs.

Thanks in advance,
Rasmus Edvardsen

EDIT: The language is C#, and it's an MVC web application.
EDIT2: John's answer solved my problem - I also had an outdated verison of itextsharp, so that answers why most other solutions I tried failed the same way.
Never meant to come off as arrogant or anything, but I realise that's how it came out. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate: 
*Which language are you working in?
*Which Frameworks are you using?

You're just passing byte[] data currently, making changes to the content will require a few additonal steps (parsing it to be understood as pdf, applying your transformations to all pages.)

Comment: *"I've tried several libraries (itext, freesharp, spire), none of correctly manipulates and outputs."* - Other programmers without any problem use iText and Spire.PDF for that task. So most likely you did something wrong. As you don't show your code for rotating, there is hardly anything else to say. (I don't know a freesharp library, so I cannot say anything about that.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample code it seems to me that you are using C# so here's a spoon feed for you.

Using [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/):

```
    private byte[] RotatePDF(byte[] pdfBytes, int rotation)
    {
        byte[] renderedBytes = null;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, ms);
            PdfReader pdfReader = null;
            PdfStamper stamper = null;
            try
            {
                document.Open();
                pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfBytes);
                stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms);

                for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfReader.GetPageN(i);
                    PdfNumber pdfRotation = pageDict.GetAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);

                    if (pdfRotation != null)
                    {
                        rotation += pdfRotation.IntValue;
                        rotation %= 360;
                    }

                    pageDict.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rotation));
                }

                pdf.AddDocument(pdfReader);
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                renderedBytes = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (pdfReader != null)
                {
                    pdfReader.Close();
                }
                if (document != null)
                {
                    document.Close();
                }
            }

            renderedBytes = ms.ToArray();

            return renderedBytes;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    var getbyteresult = WebService.GetPDFAsByteArray(pdfurl);
    getbyteresult = RotatePDF(getbyteresult, 180); // 90 180 270 360
```

Comment: You manipulate the parameter variable. Thus, from page 2 on your result may be rotated the wrong way.

Comment: @mkl I tested this already. And the manipulation is in case the document is already rotated.